# Access Contact name from visualforce in javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am on a visualforce page for a particular contact. Is there a way to access the name and id within a javascript block?

A basic example:

```
 <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="TestButton" onclick="alert({!contact.name})"/>
    </apex:form>
```

It does not recognize the contact.name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using variables in Javascript should work just fine, but you forgot the quotation marks in your code:

```
alert("{!(contact.name)}")
```

Otherwise Javascript thinks it's a variable instead of a string.

Comment: Also, prefer JSINHTMLENCODE when you do that, or `Jim "Slim Jim" Smith` will cause an error.

Comment: @sfdcfox, The JSENCODE was someone else's edit, which I just "rolled back". Was trying to reject it when someone else approved it.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track, but you currently have a syntax error in your javascript:

Your code:

```
<apex:form >
     <apex:commandButton value="TestButton" onclick="alert({!contact.name})"/>
</apex:form>
```

renders into:

```
<form>
     <input type="button" value="TestButton" onclick="alert(John Smith)"/>
</form>
```

But JS needs the name to be a string, enclosed by quote.  As such, you need to add the quotes to your VF so that they'll be rendered in the final HTML:

Adjusted code:

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton value="TestButton" onclick="alert('{!contact.name}')"/>
</apex:form>
```

renders into more-or-less the following HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="TestButton" onclick="alert('John Smith')"/>
</form>
```

Which should work.

---

Having said that, it's good practice to avoid using VF template code directly in javascript because of security risks.  As a result, you should try to do the following:

1. Any time you're using VF in javascript, use the `JSENCODE` function, ie. `alert('{!JSENCODE(Contact.Name)}')`.
2. If your Javascript is embedded inside an HTML tag or attribute (as in your example), then use `JSINHTMLENCODE` instead. (See the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm#d351894e1318) for those functions)
3. When possible, segment your code as much as possible to have a single place where you're initializing SFDC data into Salesforce.  Here's a very basic example to show the concept.  It's contrived for such a simple case - makes more sense when you're using more complicated logic.

...

```
<script>
    var contactName = '{!JSENCODE(Contact.Name)}';

    function alertGreeting() {
        alert(contactName);
    }
</script>

<apex:form >
     <apex:commandButton value="TestButton" onclick="alertGreeting();"/>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: JSINHTMLENCODE, not JSENCODE.

Comment: Good point, updated answer.

Comment: (At least, updated it in terms of how I understand JSENCODE and JSINHTMLENCODE -- if I'm wrong, can you edit?)

Comment: Looks good to me. It's just important for less experienced developers to make sure they're not exposing themselves to [Robert';) DROP TABLE Students;-- ("Little Bobby Tables")](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Exactly.  Love that link!